# How can i get This Product is already in your cart magento

Tags: product, cart, shopping-cart

i  want to show a popup if the product was added again or updated. i mean how can i get the massage "This Product is already in your cart "when second time i added product to shopping cart ....?[image]

Comment: so you want to add that message or are you wondering how you got that message?

Comment: No ,i want to add the message ..when i am adding same product ...

Comment: What have you tried to far. Did you google for any solutions or did you write any code to get this functionality?

Comment: You'll need to iterate over cart items and match between product IDs in 2 places(second place is your current product's ID). If there is a match you can display the message.